# Get the mainThread to run again?

Tags: winforms, multithreading, browser

**Hi,**

I have a winform application that is hosting a WCF Service(NamedPipes). When reciving a call a event will be triggered and then a form will be created and opened. The problem is that I get the followin exception

```
ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
```

When creating a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser in the winforms InitializeComponent method?

I Supose that another thread is running the even(working thread), how can I get the main thread to run the event?

I do not have any winform open at the time so I can´t use InvokeRequired.

**BestRegards**

Edit1 : Pleas not that I am using

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Application.Run(_instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to create a dummy winform on startup and when I need the main UI thread I will use invoke on this dummyform.

It will use some more resourse but I dont see a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of calls are made on thread pool threads.  They are not suitable to display any UI.  You'll need to create your own thread of the right flavor:

```
        var t = new Thread(() => {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

There are other practical problems you'll be battling with this, you can't just pop up a window without the user participating.  Typical mishaps are the user accidentally closing it without even seeing it or the window disappearing behind the window that the user is working with.  If you already have a user interface then be sure to use Control.BeginInvoke() to let the main thread display the window.  Consider the soft touch with a NotifyIcon, displaying a balloon in the tray notification area to alert the user.

Comment: Thanks, but where is the main UI thread? Should I not use that thread instead?

Comment: @SnowJim: Like me, I suspect Hans also assumed no UI thread existed.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The application will start with the [STAThread] public static void Main(string[] args) and then Application.Run(_instance);. I Supose that this will mean that a UI thread will be created(messagepump). My solution so far is to create a dummyForm(never shown) at startup and when UI thread is needed Invoke will be used on this dummyform. Bad/God?

Comment: That's god.  Although I have to wonder how _instance gets created and how you ensure it is never shown.  Use its BeginInvoke() method.

Answer (score 0):

That WCF call is most likely coming in on a thread other than the main UI thread. All UI controls including ActiveX ones must be created and accessed from the UI thread and only the UI thread. The error you are getting is indicating that the creating thread is not even in a Single Thread Apartment (STA) which is also a requirement.

To get the code executing on the main UI thread use the `Control.Invoke` method. It will marshal the execution of a delegate onto the thread hosting the target `Control` or `Form`.

If you do not have a reference to a `Control` or `Form` immediately available then you will need to create one. You may have to create a thread that runs a message loop as well. This can be done with `Application.Run`. It is simple enough to create a hidden `Form` that could be used to call `Invoke`.

Here is what it might look like.

```
void SomeMethodExecutingOnThreadPool()
{
  var form = null;
  var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  // Create the UI thread.
  new Thread(
    () =>
    {
      form = new Form();
      form.Load += 
        (sender, args) => 
        {
          mre.Set();
        }
      Application.Run(form);
    }).Start();

  // Wait for the UI thread to initialize.
  mre.WaitOne(); 

  // You can now call Invoke.
  form.Invoke(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: But If I create a form or a control on the current threadpool thread, will the winform not be bound to this thread? I have heard that the thread that creates the form/control have to be the thread that updates the form/control? Or will the main UI thread step in when creating a new form/control and do the work? Could you pleas provide a small example?

Comment: @SnowJim: I updated my answer. You will have to manually create a UI thread.

Comment: Thanks but this will be strange if application is running other parts on the main UI thread(with Application.Run). Could I not simple store the current UI Thread at startup in a propertie and then use this thread to trigger the event?

Comment: @SnowJim: Wait...you already have a main UI thread going? I was under the impression that was not the case. Why not use a `Form` or `Control` reference from that UI thread?  If you don't have one open then create a dummy `Form` that is always hidden.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Your suggestion with the dummyForm is infacat my solution right now but I was not sure it its the way to go.

Comment: @SnowJim: It is fine. Not ideal, but acceptable. The alternative is to do some serious hacking with `NativeWindow` by manually posting messages through the message pump and intercepting via `WndProc`. You don't want to go that route...it sucks.